# nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)?

Tags: ruby

Trying to code a puzzle based on chairs sitting in a circle. The program when ran should iterate through the array starting by deleting the first chair then `skipping` the second, deleting the third and continue this until `one chair` is left.

The program works if I type 10, then the answer is 4. When I type 20 I get the `21:in '-': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)`.

Here is my ugly code.

```
print 'Enter number of chairs? ' 
numchairs = gets.chomp.to_i

$arr = []

i=1
while i < numchairs+1 do 
  $arr.push(i)
  i+=1
end

x=0
while $arr.count > 1 do
  current=$arr[x]
  first=$arr[0]
  last=$arr[-1]

  $arr.delete_at(x)

  if (last - current) == 1 
    x=0
  elsif (last - current) == 0 
    x=1
  else
    x+=1
  end
end

print 'The survivor is sitting in chair ' 
puts $arr[0]
```

Comment: First of all: You should've included the whole error, not just part of it. The error contains line numbers.

Comment: Second, your problem is caused because you're trying to access chair `x` even though only `x-1` chairs are left.

Comment: Whoops, fixed. Error is on line 21.

Comment: This is not going to fix the issue, but it'll improve the code a bit: lines 4-10 can be simply written as `$arr = (i..numchairs).to_a`

Answer (score 1):

Because in case of input values greater than 10 you're trying to get access to array element that are placed out of the bound of array. For example, you're fetching 3-rd element of such array: `[2, 6, 10]`. This operation is returning `nil` as `current` and hence `last - current` expression is raising an `TypeError` exception.

Comment: Do you have a suggested fixes? Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: For example, change your line from elsif; x+=1; to elsif x < $arr.size - 1; x+=1; else; x=0; And please, please clean all your global variables!!